# I switched the Solution Configuration from Debug to Release and it completely destroyed my solution

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, release, solution

I've just about completed this project, so I thought I would switch from Debug to Release and test it like that... everything failed. To start with; I keep getting this XAML error : The name 'Foo' does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Bar.Snafu", when where I look into it, it clearly does...

I am also getting this error :

> x:FieldModifier cannot be specified on this tag because it has either
>   no x:Name or Name attribute set, or the tag is locally defined and has
>   a Name attribute set, which is not allowed

These two specific errors are related to custom components (not User Controls) that I am using.

Why did switching from Debug to Release do this?

Comment: Are the custom components sitting in a different assembly which is set to not build in the release configuration?

Comment: No; well, yes they are in a different assembly, but the entire thing was switched over to build in release...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the Solution in the Solution Explorer and choose Configuration Manager. What @benPearce is saying is that some projects might not be set to build in Release configuration. Select the Release configuration in the Configuration Manager and check that all the check boxes are checked.